Is it possible to make an Oracle Request from a smart contract and hide the API request?
Essentially, I have some Ethereum Smart Contracts that are going to make requests to a database of purchases from an online retailer. However, the online retailer I am working with would only like the smart contracts to be able to make API requests to the database, and does not want anyone else to be able to access this database.
This leads me to need some sort of Oracle tool that either:
Hides the API request being made in the smart contract.
Can be whitelisted to only allow my instantiation of the Oracle to make API requests.
Are either of the above possible with a Chainlink Oracle? Or is there any other type of solution with Chainlink that would allow me to achieve my desired goal? I am currently just using the Chainlink Any API product in beta testing (with a fake database).

As per your use-case, you can use Chainlink Functions.
If you want to hide the exact API, then instead of integrating the API endpoint directly, you can deploy your API onto some serverless architecture and add some some secret token or API key based authorization.
Then, that secret token can be hosted to DON or hosted to gist, in order to encrypt it before using on-chain.
You can refer to this gist, if you need the script for hosting secrets.
And, you can refer to this repo, to understand various use-cases of Chainlink Functions.
Feel free to let me know if you encounter any problems or have any doubts.
